# Accessing the literal value of the object of a triple

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, turtle-rdf, cliopatria

I'm working on a validator that validates turtle files. When working on a function to check if the cardinality that's stated is correct for each object, I can't figure out how to access the value of a literal.

The literal value is `Card=literal(type(xsd:nonNegativeInteger, '1'))` (or `1^^'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger'`).

I find a bag of properties of length L. How can I check that `L == Card`?

I already tried the following:

```
% L and Card are both 1
rdf_canonical_literal(L, LiteralL), rdf_compare(=, LiteralL, Card).
% false

rdf_canonical_literal(L, LiteralL).
% LiteralL = 1^^'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'.
```

The problem is that `xsd:integer` and `xsd:nonNegativeInteger` don't compare as equal.

However, the easiest thing to me would seem to get the value of `Card` but I really don't see how to do it. Any solutions or pointers where to find an example of this would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Solved it eventually. You can make good use of Prolog unification to get the value from the literal.

    `parse_literal(Lit, N) :-
        Lit = N^^_Type.`

Am still open to better / other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use library `rdf11` then most common datatype IRIs are automatically interpreted as Prolog values.  In other words: there is no need to convert from RDF literals to Prolog values at all.  Example:

```
?- [library(semweb/rdf11)].
?- rdf_assert(rdf:a, rdf:b, 1^^xsd:int).
?- rdf(_S, _P, N^^xsd:int).
N = 1.
```

You can extend library `rdf11` with a hook for less common datatype IRIs, e.g., I use a lot of geographic data (datatype IRI `geo:wktLiteral`) which I let `rdf/[3,4]` interpret as Prolog Well-Known Text (WKT) notation automatically.